# Is there a way to revert only certain lines from a diff hunk?

Tags: version-control, vc, diff, diff-mode

I use the builtin VC package and it's very nice that when I do a diff of changes in the current file then I can revert any hunk in the diff quickly with C-a

But sometimes I don't want to revert the whole hunk, only certain lines and keep other changes in the hunk. Is it possible somehow? Reverting individual lines, instead of the whole hunk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Magit can do this by limiting the revert action to the region.
- With the built-in `diff-mode` you can get the same kind of effect by splitting the hunk into portions using `diff-split-hunk`
  which is bound to <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> by default.

Comment: I don't use git, so I can't use magit, but I tried diff-split-hunk and it works well. Thanks!